# Move relations from EDT to table level in AX 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I was working on upgrade from ax 2009 to ax 2012. there is a relation on a edt level which i am suppossed to be moving to table level. Can anyone please tell me how this is done ?

Comment: If you find the answer useful, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Read [Migrating Extended Data Type Relations (White paper)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272870.aspx).